# How to ignore uncommited change in Github gui for MAC?

Tags: xcode, github, github-for-mac

I am using Github GUI for Mac.
Now I've some changes in my local repository, but I want to ignore them and pull latest remote repository.
I tried Repository/Pull, but got Git Error.

"•error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Classes/xxx.m
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge."

I tried Repository/Synchronize, but got following error.

"Sync Failed. Please commit all your changes before syncing."

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean using MAC GUI only, check and right click the changed files then select the discard the changes.

Answer (score 5):

Place a checkmark near each of the changed files, then go to the Repository menu and click Discard Changes to Selected Files.

Comment: I wish they had added this to the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove your uncommitted changes, just do a checkout on those files again.

Stash is super easy too though, and it keeps your changes in a local 'bucket' or stash :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I unchecked all my changes, and try to repository/pull, but got same result.

Comment: It's not a pull, it's a checkout

Comment: I mean Repository menu / Pull command in the Github Gui on Mac.

Comment: @Evert how do you `stash` on the GitHub for Mac GUI? Or is the only way to do it via the Terminal?

Comment: The lack of native stash functionality in the GitHub GUI is the only thing stopping me from using it as my primary Git GUI client. For now, I'm sticking with SmartGit.

Answer (score 0):

For those on **Github for Windows**, it is not obvious where Discard All Changes is, so I wanted to share this:

1. Select Files by using check mark next to names.
2. Right click on Collapse All/ Expand All button with two arrows. (This button is on right side of Files to Commit box, and under Sync and Gear icons.) This is where Discard All Changes is >hidden<.

*Sorry but too low level to add comment to @Leo wangs or @aspiringwebdev chain above. You gotta start somewhere...*

Comment: Github for Windows instructions can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975043/rollback-uncommited-changes-in-github-for-windows